# Is it possible to access signal in unencrypted module instance inside an encrypted module?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

An encrypted DUT RTL instantiates few instances of a non-encrypted module.
I have full visibility of the non-encrypted module.

In testbench, I want to monitor particular signal in the non-encrypted module and do run-time check. It should be something like:

```
// in top level tb
assign wire_a = encrypted_DUT.<...>.non_encrypted_inst.wire_a; // but we don't know exact path
// ... and then do some check on wire_a
```

The above line is not possible because I never know the exact path.

Is there other way? Or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the encryption is weak, placing `$display("%m")` in the un-encrypted sub-module will reveal the path in simulation.

If that doesn't work, there is a workaround. Instead of having the top level probe into the sub-module, you can have the sub-module assign to the top level signal.

```
// un-encrypted sub-module
assign $root.top_tb.wire_a = wire_a; //Note: $root is SysteVerilog only
//assign top_tb.wire_a = wire_a; //Universal but follows 'upwards name referencing'
```

IEEE1364-2001 (Verilog) § 12.5 *Upwards name referencing*
[IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) (SysteVerilog) § 23.8 *Upwards name referencing*

Comment: `$display("%m")` won't show the path, but upward referencing works as expected. I never know there is such thing. Good to know that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Having visibility to the un-encrypted lower-level modules is a security hole. Imagine a simple encrypted netlist composed of un-encrypted library cells. If you have visibility into the paths of all the cells, you could easily deduce the netlist.

The provider of the encrypted DUT would have to open the RTL to the instances they are willing to allow access to.

Comment: Hey Dave, I think the encrypted modules, provide visibility to the port connections. Not the logic, but only ports. Am I right?